# What is the difference between these blocks of code in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is not working:

```
$simple_local_avatars = new Simple_Local_Avatars;

if(isset($_POST['save_account_details'] ) ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $simple_local_avatars->edit_user_profile_update($user_id);
}
```

But this is working, just not as dynamic:

```
$simple_local_avatars = new Simple_Local_Avatars;

if(isset($_POST['save_account_details'] ) ) {
    $simple_local_avatars->edit_user_profile_update(58);
}
```

The edit_user_profile_update function expects the current logged in user id.

Answer (score 2):

Your first code block couldn't retrieve a user id, your second could. Try to `echo` the `$user_id` in your first one, it will be empty.

In other words: `get_current_user_id();` returns nothing. It's empty.

EDIT:

```
if(isset($_POST['save_account_details'] ) ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    echo $user_id;
    $simple_local_avatars->edit_user_profile_update($user_id);
}
```

Comment: Yep. but so it will be like:  $simple_local_avatars->edit_user_profile_update(echo $user_id); @michiel

Comment: That not appceted i got return 0 but follow by 2 error for at SWF sercyrity plugin in wp about the class session header.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I'm not quite sure I understand.. Can you copy paste the error?

Comment: 0

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/findgra/public_html/wp-content/plugins/avatar/index.php:464) in /home/findgra/public_html/wp-content/plugins/swiftsecurity124/helpers/wp-session-manager/includes/class-wp-session.php on line 124


Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/findgra/public_html/wp-content/plugins/avatar/index.php:464) in /home/findgra/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-phase2.php on line 62

Comment: You used a `header("Location: somefile.php");` somewhere on your page, use window.location instead.

Comment: Nop i don´t, but i think WOOCOMMECE does it, for after submit it header location me to an other page

Comment: I can't help you with this amount of information.. If you have another problem than the one in the original question, please ask a new one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like presently no user is currently logged in that's why you are getting `0` as return user id.

So try it something like that to make sure, user is logged in or not :

EDIT :

```
    if(isset($_POST['save_account_details'] ) ) {
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $user_id = $current_user->ID;
         if($user_id){
           $simple_local_avatars->edit_user_profile_update($user_id);
         }else{
                wp_die("Please log in first.");
         }

}
```

Hope it helps you ..

Comment: i get this error Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_user_logged_in() in /home/findgra/public_html/wp-content/plugins/avatar/index.php on line 463

Comment: It seems like you are using this stuff inside a plugin. So now try the edited code.